# how to include general JS in an html view of MEAN JS app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mean-stack, meanjs

I am trying add classes to html elements by JS events. Everythings works fine if i try opening the page outside(the meanjs app). If i keep it as a view of MEANJS module it wont work. THe events are not triggering at all. The JS script was inside the view code itself. How to solve this prblm?

Even the 'profileDesc' of $scope doesnt bind with the heading of second thumbnail. Whats the wrong thing over here?
Plz do help me..

```
<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,800,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="modules/core/client/css/set1.css" />
</head>
<body class="cbp-spmenu-push" ng-controller="HomeController">       
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Top Navigation -->         
            <h2 class="heading">TEAM</h2>
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                        <figure class="effect-honey">
                            <img src="modules/core/client/img/1.jpg" alt="img25"/>
                            <figcaption id="showLeftPush" ng-click="profile('kartheek')">
                                <h2>Kartheek Javvaji<span></span>&nbsp&nbsp<i>Web</i>&nbsp<i>Designer</i></h2>
                                <p class="icon-links">
                                    <a href="#"><span style="font-size:20px; float: right;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a>
                                </p>
                            </figcaption>           
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                        <figure class="effect-honey">
                            <img src="modules/core/client/img/7.jpg" alt="img26"/>
                            <figcaption id="showRightPush" ng-click="profile('kavya')">
                                <h2>{{profileDesc}} Arja<span></span>&nbsp&nbsp<i>UX</i>&nbsp<i>Designer</i></h2>
                                <p class="icon-links">
                                    <a href="#"><span style="font-size:20px; float: right;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a>
                                </p>
                            </figcaption>           
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                        <figure class="effect-honey">
                            <img src="modules\core\client\img\1.jpg" alt="img25"/>
                            <figcaption  id="showLeftPush2" ng-click="profile('balaji')">
                                <h2>Sai Balaji Kadiri<span></span>&nbsp&nbsp<i>Human</i>&nbsp<i>Resources</i></h2>
                                <p class="icon-links">
                                    <a href="#"><span style="font-size:20px; float: right;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a>
                                </p>
                            </figcaption>           
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                        <figure class="effect-honey">
                            <img src="modules/core/client/img/27.jpg" alt="img26"/>
                            <figcaption  id="showRightPush2" ng-click="profile('jane')">
                                <h2>Jane doe<span></span>&nbsp&nbsp<i>Mobile</i>&nbsp<i>Dev</i></h2>
                                <p class="icon-links">
                                    <a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com"><span style="font-size:20px; float: right;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a>
                                </p>
                            </figcaption>           
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <hr>
                <br>
        </div>
    <nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-left" id="cbp-spmenu-s1">
        <h3>profile</h3>
        <h2>Division</h2>
        <p>{{profileDesc}}</p>
        <hr>
        <h2>Division</h2>
        <p>{{profileDesc}}</p>
        <hr>
    </nav>
    <nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-right" id="cbp-spmenu-s2">
        <h3>profile</h3>
        <h2>Division</h2>
        <p>{{profileDesc}}</p>
        <hr>
        <h2>Division</h2>
        <p>{{profileDesc}}</p>
        <hr>
    </nav>      
    <script>

        var showLeftPush = document.getElementById( 'showLeftPush' ),
            showRightPush = document.getElementById( 'showRightPush' ),
            body = document.body;               
            menuLeft = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s1' ),
            menuRight = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s2' );

        showLeftPush.onclick = function() {
            //classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
            this.classList.toggle('active');
            //classie.toggle( body, 'cbp-spmenu-push-toright' );
            body.classList.toggle('cbp-spmenu-push-toright');
            //classie.toggle( menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
            menuLeft.classList.toggle('cbp-spmenu-open');
            disableOther( 'showLeftPush' );
        };

        showLeftPush.onmouseover = function() {
            this.classList.toggle('trail');
        }
        showRightPush.onmouseover = function() {
            this.classList.toggle('trail');
        }
        showRightPush.onclick = function() {
            //classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
            this.classList.toggle('active');    
            //classie.toggle( body, 'cbp-spmenu-push-toleft' );
            body.classList.toggle('cbp-spmenu-push-toleft');
            //classie.toggle( menuRight, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
            menuRight.classList.toggle('cbp-spmenu-open');
            disableOther( 'showRightPush' );
        };

        showLeftPush2.onclick = function() {
            //classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
            this.classList.toggle('active');
            //classie.toggle( body, 'cbp-spmenu-push-toright' );
            body.classList.toggle('cbp-spmenu-push-toright');
            //classie.toggle( menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
            menuLeft.classList.toggle('cbp-spmenu-open');
            disableOther( 'showLeftPush2' );
        };

        showRightPush2.onclick = function() {
            //classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
            this.classList.toggle('active');
            //classie.toggle( body, 'cbp-spmenu-push-toleft' );
            body.classList.toggle('cbp-spmenu-push-toleft');
            //classie.toggle( menuRight, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
            menuRight.classList.toggle('cbp-spmenu-open');
            disableOther( 'showRightPush2' );
        };

        function disableOther( button ) {               
            if( button !== 'showLeftPush' ) {
                //classie.toggle( showLeftPush, 'disabled' );
                showLeftPush.classList.toggle('disabled');
            }
            if( button !== 'showRightPush' ) {
                //classie.toggle( showRightPush, 'disabled' );
                showRightPush.classList.toggle('disabled');
            }
            if( button !== 'showLeftPush2' ) {
                //classie.toggle( showLeftPush, 'disabled' );
                showLeftPush2.classList.toggle('disabled');
            }
            if( button !== 'showRightPush2' ) {
                //classie.toggle( showRightPush, 'disabled' );
                showRightPush2.classList.toggle('disabled');
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('core').controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'Authentication',
  function ($scope, Authentication) {
    // This provides Authentication context.
    $scope.authentication = Authentication;
    $scope.profileDesc ='this is the profie of the person selected..!';

    $scope.profile = function (name) {
      $scope.profileDesc='This is '+name+'\'s profile';
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: All that js needs to be in directive and most of it should be removed and use angular methodology. Don't think you understand that the elements likely don't exist at the time that code runs

Comment: Using `onclick` in angular app makes no sense and is using 1990's methods mixed with 2016 angular methods. Look into core directives like `ng-click`...'ng-class` all the ng mosue events etc. then let your data model drive the dom...not native script

Comment: even a simplest JS code like <script>
document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "blue";
</script> doesnt work

Comment: Why would it? The view won't have loaded when that code runs. What you are doing is just really backwards in angular

Comment: how to do we change css classes by ng-click?....ng-class can change only by referring a var in its controller

Comment: And using controller is exactly what you should be doing. Use `ng-click` to change some property in scope model and `ng-class` would pick up the change and toggle classes appropriately

Comment: Very much thnx ....but one more prblm.....i removed JS entirely...even then the profileDesc isnt binding well. I have asigned it in the controller to a string

Comment: Not binding well? Not sure what that means.

Comment: <h2>{{profileDesc}} Arja......
this isnt being displayed as (string in $scope.profileDesc)+Arja.....instead just Arja is being displayed

Comment: Create plunker that replicates problem

Comment: uDAKfvSSsbZduJF5 plunk stream code......Its working just fine in it...with that JS and ng combination...should v do something different in MEANJS app